# О слове "лихой"

Tags: словообразование, этимология

Почему слово "лихой", происходящее от слова "лихо", то есть "зло", "горе", стало употребляться в значении "удалой"? "Лихой человек" (злодей), но в одновременно - "лихой всадник".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ЛИХОЙ-1** «причиняющий беду, злой»; **ЛИХОЙ-2** «смелый, удалой». В соврем, рус. яз. это два различных слова. Вопрос о том, развились ли они из одного источника или родственными никогда не были, решается по-разному. Одни считают, что эти значения обособились в историческое время, но развились из одного источника — праслав. *lichъ > лихъ > лихыи «большой, обильный, чрезмерный» (ср. др.-рус. слово* лихо *«много, слишком»;* лихнути *«превзойти»). Другие полагают, что в праслав.* lichъ слились прежних два слова: *likъ из* leik~- «избыточный» и *lich «злой». 
Слово **лихой** 'смелый, удалой' - содержит сему (значение) 'избыточный'.

Исчерпывающий данные об этимологии слова ЛИХОЙ можно найти в Этимологическом словаре русского языка Цыганенко.